# Service Fabric Start-Debug fails

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have been working with SF for a while now.  Recently, I began having a problem when I do a Start to debug.  The service shows in error and I get the infamous **Partition is below target replica or instance count.**. The strange thing is that I can deploy to local or remote SF provision and attach debug with no problem

I thought that something was wrong with my code, but it turns out that when I create a brand new test project, without any custom code, the same thing happens.

Note, this does not happen if I create a .net core service, only the ole .net service..

This is very strange, and I speculate that it possibly caused by the environment or VS.

I am running the latest updates on VS2017, latest SF on Windwoes 10 with latest updates..

PS: I also get the **a 64-bit debugging operation is taking longer than expected** when I exit the debugger

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall VS tools for Service Fabric and Service Fabric SDK + Runtme? I know this sounds silly but it help in many scenarios.

Comment: @OlegKarasik, indeed I did, Oleg.  This blows my mind.

Comment: Can you modify exception settings in Visual Studio to react on any thrown exception from the CLR?

Comment: @OlegKarasik i just downloaded the latest VS update ...8.9.  And the problem is gone!

Comment: I glad this magic helped!